# PHP - Illuminate/database Upsert inserting only

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Good day everyone!

I have a question regarding Upsert. I am using `illuminate/database` version `8.83`.

So my problem is that `Upsert` does not update for some reason. Researched the reason why this happens, all they did to resolve this issue, is add a unique identifier (*like ids*) in the parameters.

So here is my implementation of `upsert`:

What I wanted to do is update only the `time_unix` column but for some reason it inserts a new row. Tried some solutions that I've found like making the `id` into `UNIQUE`, but still same issue.

```php
// Format stuff
$now = date_create()->format('Y-m-d');
$unix = new DateTIme();
$unix->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Get Quarter
$qMonth = date('n', strtotime($now));
$yearQuarter = ceil($qMonth / 3);

// Things I want to upsert
$sqldata = ['day_in_month' => date('d'), 'month_id' => date('m'), 'month_name' => date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'))), 'quarter_desc' => "Q$yearQuarter", 'year' => date('Y'), 'time_unix' => $unix->getTimestamp(), 'date_full' => $now, 'quarter_id' => $yearQuarter, 'is_completed' => 0];
$colCompare = ['id'];
$colUpdate = ['time_unix'];

// Upsert
$this->queryBuilder->table('time')->upsert($sqldata, $colCompare, $colUpdate);

// Get all time where date_full -> (10/10/2022)
$timeExtracted = $this->queryBuilder->table('time')->where('date_full', '=', $now)->value('id');
```

`id: 30` should not exist and `id: 28` should have an updated `time_unix` column.

[image]

I don't really know the reason why this happens, I already provided the necessary parameters for `upsert`.

**Additional Information:**

It is mentioned in the documentation that the MySQL database driver ignores the second argument of the `upsert` method and always uses the `primary` and `unique` indexes of the table to detect existing records. But for some reason it still inserts rather than updating the existing record/row.

Comment: You need to ensure that id is included in the `$sqldata`. Could you try that and see whether it helps you.

Comment: @AaronT just tried it, didn't work. It still inserts a new row.

Comment: As I remember, `upsert` should warp with `array/[]`.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam yeah just tried it, didn't work. Same result. Or maybe im missing something.

Comment: @JohnDoe try this and see `DB::table('time')->upsert([ $sqldata ], ['id'] , ['time_unix']);`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Yeah it didn't work, still the same result. I feel like i'm missing something here but idk what.

Answer (score 0):

This is my **temporary** solution for my issue. I will come back with some solutions for this `upsert` issue.

```php
$timeExtracted = $this->queryBuilder->table('time')->where('date_full', '=', $now)->value('id');

if($timeExtracted) {
    $this->queryBuilder->table('time')->where('date_full', '=', $now)->update(['time_unix' => $unix->getTimestamp()]);
} else {
    $this->queryBuilder->table('time')->insert($sqldata);
}
```